# MySQL Replication don't run after configuring

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication

I'm practicing mysql replication with 2 Centos 6.9 64bit virtual machine. Setting process was fine but after I insert data to master server, Anythings happens in slave.

**MASTER SETTING**

*mysql.cnf*

```
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
symbolic-links=0


log-bin=mysql-bin
binlog-do-db=dbtest
server-id=1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
sync_binlog=1

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

*mysql> show master status*

```
mysql-bin.000002 |    13069 | dbtest
```

*mysql> show processlist*

```
 145 | root | 192.168.1.11:45148 | NULL       | Binlog Dump |  810 | Has sent all binlog to slave; waiting for binlog to be updated | NULL
```

**SLAVE SETTING**

*my.cnf*

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
symbolic-links=0

#Replication
server-id=2
replicate-do-db=dbtest
master-host=192.168.1.10
master-user=root
master-password=master_password

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

*mysql> show slave status*

```
Slave_IO_State : Waiting for master to send event
Master_Host : 192.168.1.10
Master_User : root
Master_Port : 3306
Connect_Retry : 60
Master_Log_File : mysql-bin.000002
Read_Master_Log_Pos : 12954 
Relay_Log_File : mysqld-relay-bin.000017 
Relay_Log_Pos : 251
Relay_Master_Log_File :  mysql-bin.000002 
Slave_IO_Running : Yes
Slave_SQL_Running : Yes
Replicate_Do_DB : dbtest
Last_Errno : 0
Skip_Counter : 0
Exec_Master_Log_Pos : 12954
Relay_Log_Space : 552
Until_Condition : None
Until_Log_Pos : 0
Master_SSL_Allowed : No
Seconds_Behind_Master : 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert : No
Last_IO_Errno : 0
Last_SQL_Errno : 0
```

*mysql> show processlist*

```
 5 | system user |                 | NULL       | Connect | 1251 | Waiting for master to send event | NULL
```

I follow [this guide](http://www.techoism.com/how-to-configure-master-slave-mysql-replication-on-centosrhel/). Thanks for your help.

Comment: Replication looks fine. Apart from small differences in master log pos. Using replication filters has effects on how you. Is `dbtest` the default database when you did the `INSERT`? Avoid replication filters unless necessary, and if not, read the documentation very carefully.

Comment: No. `dbtest` is created. And I have a small question in master processlist. Why do master connect to slave in port `45148`. And this port always change when I check. Something wrongs in it?

Comment: If you `INSERT INTO dbtest.table...`, and `dbtest` isn't the default database, it won't be replicationed. The slave connects to the master on destination port 3306. The source port, the 45148 is usually autoallocated. The tcp connection on the master will look like its connected to the port `45148'. This is quite normal.

Comment: Oh, something I don't understand here. I think default database just in a session when I use `use` comment, when I connect to mysql by myself. 
But in the process  of replicating automatically, how do I configure it to be the default? I'm new here, sorry ;))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default database is from `use db` or from the database listed when you connect.

Replication filtering has a large list of rules in the manual: [Evaluation of Database-Level Replication and Binary Logging Options](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-rules-db-options.html) is the full text. Only use it when you need it, it will be easier that way.